# Как узнать с какого города заходили на сайт?

Tags: html, php, javascript

как это можно сделать с высокой долей вероятности? только ли по IP? пожалуйста, приведите конкретные статьи или лучше конкретный код, как это сделать. задача: вывод города, в котором в данный момент находится посетитель моего сайта. например Москва, Воронеж итп

Comment: есть ещё [HTML5 geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo)

Comment: @jackair7, вы не шпион, случайно?

Comment: @eicto, он только с GPS/WiFi данные снимать умеет, похоже. На стационарном компе выводит ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Это будет IP, самое простое решение тут: http://ross.vc/?p=204
Гитхаб: https://github.com/rossvs/ipgeobase.php

```
require_once("ipgeobase.php");
$gb = new IPGeoBase();
$data = $gb->getRecord('46.46.152.210');
var_dump($data);
```

Получаем в ответ:

```
array(7) {
  ["range"]=>
  string(27) "46.46.128.0 - 46.46.169.255"
  ["cc"]=>
  string(2) "RU"
  ["city"]=>
  string(6) "Москва"
  ["region"]=>
  string(6) "Москва"
  ["district"]=>
  string(29) "Центральный федеральный округ"
  ["lat"]=>
  string(9) "55.755787"
  ["lng"]=>
  string(9) "37.617634"
}
```

Comment: Насколько четко определяется город? Какова вероятность ошибки? Я такой допытливый потому что для меня это действительно важно и велика цена ошибки

Comment: Вероятность ошибки довольно велика. Лично у меня любой сервис геолокации пишет, что я нахожусь в Германии, хотя я нахожусь на юго-западе Москвы, причём никакими прокси я не пользуюсь. Всё зависит от провайдера.

Comment: Скрипт переехал на http://ross.pp.ru/?p=204